# How to build a distribution of percentages in U-SQL?

Tags: u-sql

In my database I have the column "Study hours per week". I want to build a distribution using U-SQL which groups the % of students into each 'student hour' bucket. Is there a built-in function to help me achieve this?

Essentially, I want to populate the right side of this table:

**Study Hours per week**       |     **% of students**

<= 1

<= 5

<= 10

<= 20

<= 40

<= 100

**Example**: If we had 10 unique students with the following study hours/week: [5, 6, 10, 9, 2, 25, 18, 5, 12, 1] the resulting output should be:

**Study Hours per week**       |     **% of students**

<= 1  | 10%

<= 5  | 40%

<= 10 | 70%

<= 20 | 90%

<= 40 | 100%

<= 100| 100%

Comment: Can you provide some sample student data and expected results please?

Comment: Added summary of sample data and expected output to the question.